# Mocha tests timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a unit test to register function. I return a promise and I receive an error:

```
Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I've tried with done() function, async await, checking Promise reject - with no result.

My test code below:

```js
import authController from '../../../src/controllers/authController';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('Test register method', () => {
    it('Register method should create new user', () => {
        const req = {
            file: sinon.spy(),
            body: {
                name: "John",
                email: "johndoe@example.com",
                phone: "123",
                gender: "Male",
                birthDate: "12-12-1992",
                purpose: "Friends",
                password: "Secret"
            }
        };
        const res = {
            status: function () {
                return this;
            },
            json: sinon.spy()
        };
        return authController.register(req,res).then(() => {
            expect(res.json.firstCall.lastArg.success).to.equal(true);

        });
    });
});
```

Code of the tested controller:

https://github.com/elszczepano/FindMates-API/blob/master/src/controllers/authController.js

Comment: Does that code work outside the test ? (or can you confirm that `register` is actually resolving?)

Comment: Yes, when I'am using Postman and test my code manually all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
First:
I had to set a timeout in package.json to 10000 milliseconds:

```
"test": "nyc mocha --require @babel/register --require @babel/polyfill tests/unit/**/*.test.js --timeout 10000"
```

Second:
I had to create a connection with my MongoDB database (and disconnection after tests of course).

```js
before(done =>{
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/FindMates', {useNewUrlParser: true });
    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
    done();
});
after(done => {
    mongoose.disconnect();
    done();
});
```